# Routing a dynamic controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I need to routing a dynamic controller for example:

- example.com/user1
- example.com/user2
- example.com/user3
- example.com/usernnnnn

and too

example.com/about (not dynamic)
example.com/contact (not dynamic)

Comment: user1 & user2 - parameter or controller name ?

Comment: parameter, but I need to redirect to specific controller, for example controller "user", but the parameter can be anything different to "About", "Contact", "Login", etc

When I go to example.com/about --> I need to redirect to controller="Home", Action="About".

When I go to example.com/contact --> I need to redirect to controller="Home", Action="Contact".

But if is another parameter for example: example.com/tomas-anderson --> I need to redirect to controller="User", Action="Index" , Parameter="tomas-anderson".

you know what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

so you can try

```
   routes.MapRoute(null,
         "{Controller}/{id}",
           new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new { id = @"user\d{1,9}*?" });
```